# Use different AppData folders for Debug and Release builds of an application

Tags: appdata

If I have an application named `MyApplication`, is it possible to have a custom location for the local `AppData` directory of this application? E.g.: `C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\MyApplication2`. I can't find anywhere how to change this.

EDIT

Clarification: I don't want to create an auxiliary directoy called `C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\MyApplication2`. I want the system to recognize `C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\MyApplication2` as the actual local `AppData` directory of `MyApplication`.

EDIT 2:

I really need a way to have both debug and release versions installed on my computer in order to be as close as possible to reality. Until now I managed to change where the application is installed and other application level identificators, but I couldn't change the `AppData` in order for each of them to use different settings files.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would you expect this to accomplish? It's a system wide setting, so all you'd do is make it so any other app (or the OS itself) that uses %LOCALAPPDATA% would end up creating its folders beneath your application folder there.

Comment: I really need a way to have both debug and release versions installed on my computer in order to be as close as possible to reality. Until now I managed to change where the application is installed and other application level identificators, but I couldn't change the `AppData` in order for each of them to use different settings files.

Comment: So why do you need to change the entire OS location of LOCALAPPDATA? Create two folders (%LOCALAPPDATA%\MyApp\Debug and %LOCALAPPDATA%\MyApp\Release) and a compiler define or command line switch or whatever based on whether it's debug or release to use the appropriate folder. E.g., #IFDEF DEBUG.

Comment: Hmm, this never crossed my mind. Can you add this as an answer in order for me to accept it? I will actually leave the release version like it is (because users have already installed the application) and I will create a `%LOCALAPPDATA%\MyApp\Debug` like you said, for the debug version only on my PC.

Comment: I can do that, if you can edit your question to put the contents of your previous comment (the one starting with *I really need a way*) so that there's something in the question I can answer.  :-)

Comment: I added the explanation as to why I need this

Comment: I added an answer, with an example of one way to approach the issue. It may give you an idea of how to handle things without the global change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to move the location of `{localappdata}` if you're just wanting to change the location while developing your code on your machine. In fact, there's no need to get Inno Setup involved in this at all.

Just define a local variable in your code based on the value of a compiler define (such as `#IFDEF DEBUG`, for instance). Create the %LOCALAPPDATA%\MyApplication2 folder during the installation. When `DEBUG` is defined, append to that location at runtime (which would be during development) to read/write your configuration info from a Debug folder.

I don't know what language you're coding in, but in Delphi it would go something like this:

```
{$IFDEF DEBUG}
const
  ConfigDir = 'Debug\';
{$ENDIF}

// At application startup, retrieve the contents of %LOCALAPPDATA% via API call
// or by retrieving the contents of the environmental variable (say into the
// DataDir variable). Then...
{$IFDEF DEBUG}
DataDir := DataDir + ConfigDir;
// If needed, you can check here for whether the folder exists and
// create it if it doesn't.
{$ENDIF}
```

Now all of your code accessing the config info just retrieves it from `DataDir`, which will adjust based on whether you're in Debug or Release mode.